Why to_date on a DATE column in Oracle increases performance?
I have an Oracle SQL Query running for hours. The rows returned is only 10k. Surprisingly, when I use TO_DATE in the joins, it returns data in 10 secs. columns on both the sides are datatype DATE. Can anyone please explain why its having this behaviour?
AND to_date(C_DT.CALC_DT) = CE_ABS.CALC_DT
AND to_date(C_DT.CALC_DT) = CE_VEH.CALC_DT


Would be helpful to add the explain output for both queries to the question, and the schema for the relevant tables.

best guess, CACL_DT isn't actually a DATE - see above comment, include the table structures and execution plans - also make sure the STATS are up to date on your tables/indexes

it could also be that you have an index being used on those date columns that is hurting you... adding a function throws out index use, which could be flipping the plan to a more optimal hash join. As was already stated, you really need to generate an execution plan.
